# Dynamic Array List in Java

Tags: java

I have some lines of java code

```
class FileManager
{
    File f = new File("SD.DAT");

    public void wsv(ArrayList<Student> list) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(list);
            fos.close();
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(FileManager.class.getName()).log(L evel.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> rsv() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        if (!f.exists())
        {
            return new ArrayList<SinhVien>();
        }

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        return (ArrayList<Student>) ois.readObject();
    }
}
```

I want to ask:
In the below code, what does:

```
public void wsv(ArrayList<Student> list) 

public ArrayList<Student> rsv()
```

mean?

Why it has to return `(ArrayList<Student>) ois.readObject();`

I don't understand about array, so I hope you can show it to me.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, the Student class implements the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

This code is an example for serialization/deserialization. In the method wsv() an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of Student instances is serialized and written to a file using a FileOutputStream. In the other method rsv() the same file is read , the same file is read (if the file exists), the content is deserialized using an ObjectInputStream, the result is casted to an ArrayList and returned.

See the Javadoc of [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) as an introduction to serialization and deserialization of objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void wsv(ArrayList<Student> list)
```

This is a method accepting an arrayList as a parameter.  The arrayList is a collection of Student objects.  So it can be invoked with...

```
List<Student> myList = new ArrayList<Student>();
wsv(myList);
```

It also has no return value (it's void), consider the method below.

```
public ArrayList<Student> rsv()
```

This does need to return a value (an ArrayList of type Student), but is invoked with no method parameters.  The return is cast from an Object to an ArrayList with...

```
return (ArrayList<Student>) ois.readObject();
```

Consider having a quick read of [casting](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1170)

Answer (score 1):

First method is ::

```
public void wsv(ArrayList list)
```

From my point of view here wsv means Write .

It writes the arrayList of Student in file

AND::

```
public ArrayList rsv()
```

means Read

It reads  the arrayList of Student from file and if not found return the new one

This is an example of Object Serialization and deserialization

Answer (score 1):

Why it has to return `(ArrayList<Student>) ois.readObject();`
Because method signature is

```
 public ArrayList<Student> rsv() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
```

It is expecting a ArrayList of type Student in return.

```
(ArrayList<Student>) ois.readObject();
```

reads a serialized object and casts to ArrayList of type Student which is then returned from the method.

Answer (score 1):

They are both method signatures. The first indicates a method which does not return a value, indicated by `void`, and accepts and `ArrayList` containing `Student` objects as it's only argument:

```
public void wsv(ArrayList<Student> list)
```

A method with a `void` return type does not require a `return` statement to be present in the method-body.

The second, returns an `ArrayList` that will contain `Student` objects and accepts no arguments:

```
public ArrayList<Student> rsv()
```

`public` is an access modifier, which controls the visibility of the methods, i.e where the method can be invoked from.

If we break down the code we can see why you need `(ArrayList<Student>) ois.readObject()`.

`readObject()` returns an `Object`, this cannot be returned from the method, only `ArrayList<Student>` is acceptable:

```
final Object object = ois.readObject();
```

Therefore we need to cast the object, e.g. make it appear as another type:

```
final ArrayList<Student> students = (ArrayList<Student>) object;
```

This can now be returned from the method:

```
return students;
```

We can cast the `Object` to `ArrayList<Student>`, somewhat safely, in this situation if we can be sure that the object read is really of the type `ArrayList<Student>`. Otherwise casting can be a dangerous situation and may throw a `ClassCastException` when trying to cast to a type that isn't possible, for example:

```
final String string = (String) ois.readObject();
```

I hope that helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

All the remaining answers pretty much clarify the matter. I just thought to add this in light of your statement :

> I don't understand about array, so I hope you can show it to me.

`array` is a collection of similar data types. For example:
 `int num = new int[2];` 
creates an array of length 2 with data type `int`.

Now you can fill it up with `int` data.

Say: `num[0] = 1, num[1] = 5`

But arrays have fixed length.

So we use collections instead. In your case `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList<Student>` implies that it is a collection of `Object`s of type `Student`.